# GSON error in HTC Explorer

Tags: android, gson

Currently I'm working in a project which is using GSON Library. The problems occurs when I run my application in HTC explorer. The GSON class constructor generate the follow exception:

**No-args constructor for class  does not exist. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type to fix this problem.**

I've tested the application in a lot of devices. In fact the application has a lot of downloads, and any one of them has any crash like this.

Any ideas? I've seen some other post but I couldn't fixed the bug.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Download [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/downloads/list)
2. Put jarjar-1.0.jar and gson-1.5.jar in the same folder
3. Create a new text file in this folder (rules.txt)
4. Write the following line in the textfile: rule com.google.gson.** com.google.myjson.@1
5. From the commandline, open jarjar with the command "java -jar jarjar.jar process rules.txt gson-1.5.jar myjson-1.5.jar"
6. Replace the gson library in your project with myjson and update the imports

Don't use the GSON jar file, use the new myjson. 
Ans also make sure the library is selected in Order and Export (Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer kabuki. But I'd like to know why I should do this? And what's the problem?

Comment: well what my understanding is that, HTC phones might have package same as GSON package name, and because of which clas cast exception occurs, it happened with me in HTC EVO 4G.

Comment: Uoh!Okey I'll try it! I hope it keep works in others devices. I'll tell you something. Thanks again.

Comment: You save my life. Thanks a lot!! It works nicely! So, it keep working with other phones like: Samsung, Sony, Nexus..?